# Convert Excel VBA Range for Use in Excel Function

Tags: excel, vba

I want to place a VLOOKUP formula into an Excel cell from within a VBA macro.  The range to be used as the VLOOKUP's second argument is identified in the macro as a Range object.  The range is two columns wide but a variable number of rows.  Here's the macro code I have that obviously throws an Excel error:

```
Dim processedRow As Integer
Dim rngVlookupData As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
... code ...
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HR Eval Report")
ws.Range("BC8", "BBD8").Select
ws.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Set rngVlookupData = Selection
Range(Cells(processedRow, 26), Cells(processedRow, 26)) = "=IF(VLOOKUP(Z7,rngVlookupData,1)=Z7,""Yes"","""")"
Range("AA5") = "=IF(VLOOKUP(Z7,rngVlookupData,1)=Z7,VLOOKUP(Z7,rngVlookupData,2),"""")"
```

Obviously, Excel doesn't recognize "rngVlookupData", which causes a #NAME error.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is being treated as a string. You this

```
Range("AA5").Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(Z7," & _
                       rngVlookupData.Address & _
                       ",1)=Z7,VLOOKUP(Z7," & _
                       rngVlookupData.Address & _
                       ",2),"""")"`
```

Comment: As far as I know, default property of range object is value. To get the address you need to use rngVlookupData.address

Comment: @MátéJuhász: I think you may have forgotten to refresh the page :)